# Some PIL.ImageFile attributes like LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES are missed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, intel-edison

I'm working on the Intel Edison that have custom distribution that built using Yocto project, the exact python version that I'm working on is 2.7.3 and the PIL version is 1.1.7.

While trying to enable truncated images loading by setting the LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES attribute to true, I found that it is not existed on the Edison, where it is existed on my Ubuntu that have the same PIL version.

Is there any other way to enable truncated images loading, is that feature not supported on Edison, why such as future being missed where it is existed on other machine that have the same PIL version?

I'm a new Linux user, sorry if that looks like a dummy question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES` option isn't available in PIL. It was introduced into Pillow, a fork of PIL. (It was added in [Pillow 2.0.0](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/54d4f5eb3c1a465db145698079148103e3a9039f).)

The last [PIL release was five years ago](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), but [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) is a maintained fork of PIL.

Remove PIL first then install Pillow:

`pip install pillow`